# Associating unique properties to anonymous functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's a standard way of associating unique properties to anonymous JavaScript functions while creating them so that these properties can be accessed within the functions themselves when they are executed (i.e. run time)?

A scenario is this:

*Say I have events which I want to bind to dynamically generated anonymous functions.*

```
var events = ['connect','disconnect','error','connect_failed'];

for(a in events){
  var handler = function(){
     // console.log(arguments.callee.custom); // Not reliable 'cos callee is supposedly deprecated
     console.log('<event-name>');
  };
  handler.custom = events[a];
  $(window).on(events[a],handler);
}
```

Since using **arguments.callee** is deprecated and not guaranteed to be optimal on all platforms. What's the recommended way of achieving something similar to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `handler.custom` in your function, too:

```
var handler = function() {
  console.log(handler.custom);
  console.log('<event-name>');
};
```

To prevent scoping issues in case of asynchronous callbacks, you can create a newly scoped `handler` function by wrapping your code in a closure:

```
for(a in events){
  (function() {
    var handler = function(){
      console.log(handler.custom);
      console.log('<event-name>');
    };
    handler.custom = events[a];
    $(window).on(events[a],handler);
  })();
}
```

**EDIT**: just realized you can use `forEach` as well (although that also suffers from browser compatibility issues):

```
events.forEach(function(event) {
  var handler = function() {
    ...
  };
  handler.custom = event;
  $(window).on(event,handler);
});
```

Comment: I especially like the scoped handler within a closure

Answer (score 1):

Named function expressions give a reference to the function itself only within the function scope:

```
var events = ['connect', 'disconnect', 'error', 'connect_failed'];

for (var a in events) {
  var handler = function inside() {
     console.log(inside.custom); // not deprecated
     console.log('<event-name>');
  };
  handler.custom = events[a]; // now will stay with function even if renamed or moved
  $(window).on(events[a], handler);
}
```

However, Internet Explorer 8 and below will not parse named functions correctly - Juriy Zaytsev explains the exact issue behind them in more detail: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#named-expr

If you really have to target IE8 and below, either stick with arguments.callee or use conditional compilation for IE, which is basically IE conditional comments for JavaScript.

Comment: +1 for using named function expressions, really elegant solution IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean... 
you want event name when the event is triggered and want to know which event has triggered at run time in function... Am I Right? then you can use Event Object received in handler...
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EADkz/1/)**

```
var events = ['connect','disconnect','error','connect_failed'];

for(a in events){
  var handler = function(e){
     console.log(e.type); 
      console.log('<event-name>');
  };
  $(window).on(events[a],handler);
}

for(a in events){
  $(window).trigger(events[a]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var events = ['connect','disconnect','error','connect_failed'];

function assignHandler(eventType, custom) {
   $(window).on(events[a], function() {
      console.log(custom);
   });
}   

for(a in events){
  assignHandler(events[a], events[a]);
}
```

The magic of JS closures means that the anonymous function assigned as an event handler inside `assignHandler()` will be able to access the `custom` argument of `assignHandler()` *even after `assignHandler()` has finished.*

However, since you seem to be using jQuery's [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handlereventObject) you don't need to implement anything yourself because jQuery already has functionality for this:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

Note the optional third argument is `data`. Within the event handler this can be accessed as [`event.data`](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

```
for(a in events){
  var handler = function(e){
     console.log(e.data);
     console.log('<event-name>');
  };
  var custom = events[a];
  $(window).on(events[a], null, custom, handler);
}
```